# Calling Last fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have main activity,which has three fragments fragements A,Fragements B,Fragement C.

Fragment A is the first fragment when activity is launched.

Each fragments is a grid view where each item click opens a new fragmentactivity.

The problem is if I am on Fragement C and I click on item it opens a new Fragement activity.When I press back button it takes me to fragment A, which is not right it should have been Fragement C.

How can I go back to Fragement from where I went to Fragement activity??

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: An new empty FragmentActivity? Code will help. If you are concerned about privacy, we just need the method that is invoked when an item is clicked on Fragment C.

Comment: You should upload code so,people can find exact problem in code. and as per my experience i think are you add fragment over there. you should replace fragment instead of add fragment,